# Icon doesn't display in qt designer made dialog for QGIS

Tags: qt, icons, qgis

this is my first QT designer project, and I haven't found an answer for my problem, I designed a dialog for QGIS, I included an icon, with the label display widget, set it up from the resource file, but it won't show in QGIS, at first it didn't even recognized the font and font size I set up in QT, but changing the style Sheet directly in the object inspector fixed that, now I just can't make the icons appear in QGIS, I tried .png and .ico and minimal size, I tried editing the .qrc and .ui file, but nothing works, do I need a python script for that?, what am I missing??

When I preview the dialog in QT it shows ok, and the deafult icons appear in QGIS

I am using QGIS 2.18 and QT designer 4.8.5

Thanks

Comment: Please,provide any python code,screenshot....To be able to help you better

Answer (score 0):

After you have replaced the icon file you need to recompile with the command make